# Z80 ctc gold ICs speed

Tags: hardware, z80

Does anyone have any information on what is the maximum speed for the gold ceramic z80 CTC? [image: A gold ctc from ebay]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since it's labeled Z80-CTC, it's a 2.5 MHz type (Z80A-CTC would be 4 MHz).

Gold or not gold cap doesn't make any difference.

Without a further marking its temperature range is 0-70°C. Wider temperature ranges where are avalable in ceramic but marked CE (Extended) and CM (Military).

(Information taken from a Feb 1980 product sheet)

Comment: I was hoping it would imply it's a 10mhz one , unfortunatly not :( .I was asking because the naming usually goes like : z84c3010<speed>  and there was no such marking there. anyway, thanks

Comment: 10 MHz in 1978? ... nice try :)) The Z84xx designation was introduced way later, IIRC in 1981

Comment: So there are no gold z80 related ICs that can go up to 10mhz? It would really suck because they are gorgeous

Comment: Ther can be, but since the package is not realy related here, it doesn't matter. Keep in mind, tehre are many beautiful sports cars that can't compete to a stupid VW family car.

Comment: The maximum speed of an IC like that is likely determined by binning, not different production method - so one out of a couple of gold capped ones just might work perfectly at 10MHz.